# Android: setting new Alarm from onReceive method

Tags: android, service, android-activity, alarmmanager, alarm

I have a collection of reminders in my database(sort by time). When my application starts I call `setAlarm`. I need to add code in `onReceive` method in order to do these tasks:

1. Get first reminder from my database
2. Get the delay associated to the reminder
3. Schedule a new Alarm for getting the next reminder.

I created a simple BroadcastReceiver class:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    private static final String DEBUG_TAG= "AlarmReceiver";

    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"ALARM!!!");
            // --mycode--
    }
}
```

and the Activity class:

```
public class AlarmActivity extends Activity {

    private Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
        context = getApplicationContext();
    }


    public void setAlarm(View v){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()+ Delay,pendingIntent);
        Log.i("SETTER","Alarm started");

    }

    public void stopAlarm(View v){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        pendingIntent.cancel();
    }
}
```

Now, I would that in the `--mycode--` section new Delay is taken (if exists) from database and new Alarm is setted with this new Delay. 
How can I set a new AlarmManager from onReceive method?

Comment: Can you explain more in details its hard to get

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get `AlarmManager` in the broadcast receiver by accessing it from the context

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)arg0.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
```

where `arg0` is your context variable